As defined internally <image> in A-Frame
If under the hood:
<a-box color="red" depth="0.5" height="0.5" shader="flat" width="0.5"></a-box>
is:
<a-entity geometry="primitive: box; depth: 0.5; height: 0.5; width: 0.5" material="color: red; shader: standard"></a-entity>
Can the <text> tag be defined as an entity, with what parameters?
Using the inspector, by selecting an object from the stage and copying the entity to the clipboard, what is originally defined as  or , becomes an entity.
